# AWS RDS DB Parameter Group in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-rds, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create a custom DBParameterGroup as part of the CloudFormation stack to launch SQL instance using below resource definition -

```
CustomDBParameterGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
    Properties:
      Description: !Join [' ', ['Custom Option Group for application - ', !Ref AppName, !Ref EnvironmentType]]
      Family: sqlserver-ee-13.0
      Parameters:
        remote_access: 0
```

When I launch the stack, I get the error -

`Invalid / Unsupported DB Parameter: remote_access`

> What is the correct parameter attribute key/value combination to
>   disable remote access in the parameter group? Unable to find this in
>   AWS documentation. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Change the `remote_access` to `remote access` (with a space) and the custom DBParameterGroup will be created with the set value of 0.

```
CustomDBParameterGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup
    Properties:
      Description: !Join [' ', ['Custom Option Group for application - ', !Ref AppName, !Ref EnvironmentType]]
      Family: sqlserver-ee-13.0
      Parameters:
        remote access: 0
```